# What does the syntax m = z<p mean in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, syntax

```
from pylab import *
L = 20
p = 0.5
z = rand(L,L)
m = z<p
imshow(m, origin=’lower’)
show()
```

In this code, what the the m = z < p syntax mean ?

Comment: `z<p` is a condition, whose return value, `True` or `False` would be assigned to `m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might be a good example as to why variable naming matters. In this piece of code, `m` is a boolean (meaning true or false) variable that is true if the variable `z` is strictly less than the variable `p`.

I suspect you are either no programmer yourself or just starting, so I figure you might find https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers useful for extra info.